# best practice for mysql search query (select)?

Tags: php, mysql, select

what is the best practice for data search in mysql:
1- to extract 100 record  then do filtering outside the database or to use `WHERE` in mysql database and extract the exact needed record even if if `WHERE` is going to be a little complicated (also concerning indexing columns)
2- to use or not to `JOIN`

Comment: Definitely not the first option.

Comment: Use `JOIN` when joining results from multiple tables. It seems pretty self-evident.

Answer (score 2):

Doing filtering outside the database is a sign you're doing it wrong. `WHERE` exists to do the filtering for you. If your conditions take a long time to apply, you probably need to index better.

Using `EXPLAIN` can help identify where problems in your query exist.

If you can't figure out how to tune your `JOIN`, you can try deliberately de-normalizing your data to improve performance. Keep in mind that requires duplicating data and keeping it in sync so it's something that is usually a last resort.